# How to scrape the data from Wikipedia by category?

Tags: python, wikipedia

I would like to use only medical data from Wikipedia for analysis. I use python for scraping. 
I have used this library for searching by word in query:

```
import wikipedia

import requests
import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
wikipedia.set_lang("en")
query = raw_input()
WikiPage = wikipedia.page(title = query,auto_suggest = True)
cat = WikiPage.categories
for i in cat:
    print i
```

and get the categories.

But, my problem is vice versa:

I want to give category, for example: health or medical terminology and get all articles with this type.

how can I do this?

Comment: Please don't target a badly written bot at a website. *cough @AlexClark *

Comment: "Please do not use a web crawler" There are API's available. There is even a file available containing all information in the database: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: ok. It is good. But I have downloaded the whole database. How can I choose only medical articles?

Comment: As an alternative to processing the database offline, the page [CategoryTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CategoryTree) demonstrates how to programmatically query the server for category (and page) listings for a given category name. Maybe this is easier than processing GBs of data.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit: actual answer

There is [API:Categorymembers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers), which documents usage, parameters and gives examples on "how to retrieve lists of pages in a given category, ordered by title". It won't save you from having to descend through the category tree (cf. below) yourself, but you get a nice entry point and machine-readable results.

#### Old answer: related information

A very brief pointer is given on the [Help:Category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Category) page, section *[Searching for articles in categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Category#Searching_for_articles_in_categories)*:

> In addition to browsing through hierarchies of categories, it is
>   possible to use the search tool to find specific articles in specific
>   categories. **To search for articles in a specific category, type
>   incategory:"CategoryName" in the search box.**
>
> An "OR" can be added to join the contents of one category with the
>   contents of another. For example, enter
>
> ```
>     incategory:"Suspension bridges" OR incategory:"Bridges in New York City"
> ```
>
> to return all pages that belong to either (or both) of the categories,
>   as here.
>
> Note that using search to find categories will not find articles which
>   have been categorized using templates. **This feature also doesn't
>   return pages in subcategories.**

To address the subcategory problem, the page [Special:CategoryTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CategoryTree) can be used instead. However, the page does not point to an obvious documentation. So I think the `<form>` fields must be manually searched for in the page source to create a programmatic API.

Comment: Thanks very much. I suppose, I will download the whole latest dump  and then, by looking at the categories\subcategories schema, I will try to select only Medical articles. How do you find this idea?

Comment: You might find this article useful :- https://kodingnotes.wordpress.com/2014/12/03/parsing-wikipedia-page-hierarchy/

Also, if you can select a couple of top level categories of interest, it's pretty straightforward after that. The link mentioned above, traverses bottom-up, but it's straightforward to use his logic to traverse top-down.